# TableVIew Problem

Tags: iphone

i i want to activate scrolling vertically through programming for 2 UITableview at sametime?(one table view length 160,another one has 160).is it possible ?In one Viewcontroller's view i have scrollview, on that i have two tableviews(instead of one,like two column)..how can i scroll vertically both at same time?any help please?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement 2 separated and round-rected columns then it might make some sense.

In any other case just use one UITableView and separate each cell visually (the left half will display the data for the first column and the right - for the second).

If you still want to have 2 separate table views and have them both scrolled simultaneously then get rid of the containing scroll view and implement the `UIScrollViewDelegate` as was already suggested.
Something like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    self.leftTableView.contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    self.rightTableView.contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
}
```

I think that this code should do the magic...

Don't forget to set the view controller to be the delegate of both table views.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get it but a table View on top of a scroll View will create problems. Because, when users scroll, both of the views will try to get the interaction of the user, and they can take turn to get that interaction randomly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a picture, or clearer description of what you want?

If your next question is "how do I make the scroll views stay at the same offset?" -- i.e. you want them to sync vertically -- than I would advise that you abandon the idea of using two UITableViews.

Instead, define a two-column UITableViewCell, which can easily be done with Interface Builder, and use that to give the appearance of two columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think that doing away with neither UITableView’s `userInteractionEnabled` set to `YES`, and implementing your own `touchesMoved:withEvent:` method (maybe also try `UIGestureRecognizer`s) would prove fruitful.

I am guessing that these `UITableView`s are not used to show plain tabular data but images or other content, and have a different interaction paradigm (e.g., when the two fingers slide separately the two table views scroll in separate velocity & direction).  If that is the case you might ultimately want to use custom controls.

But if you just want a 2-column `UITableView` then as Jonathan said, simply use a two-column cell.